# What's an example of a utility program that the env command could call?

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

After taking a look at the [env command man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/env.1.html) I was curious to see an example of a utility program that would be used in the usage noted below?

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> env [-i] [name=value ...] [utility [argument ...]]
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> env executes utility after modifying the environment as specified on the command line.  The option
>        name=value specifies an environmental variable, name, with a value of value.  The option `-i' causes
>        env to completely ignore the environment it inherits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common use is to launch interpreters, by making use of the fact that `env` will search $PATH for the command it is told to launch. Since the [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) requires an absolute path to be specified, and since the location of various interpreters (`perl`, `bash`, `python`) may vary **a lot**, it is common to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

instead of trying to guess whether it is `/bin/perl`, `/usr/bin/perl`, `/usr/local/bin/perl`, `/usr/local/pkg/perl`, `/fileserver/usr/bin/perl`, or `/home/MrDaniel/usr/bin/perl` on the user's system...

On the other hand, `env` is almost always in `/usr/bin/env`. (Except in cases when it isn't; some systems might use `/bin/env`, but that's a fairly rare occassion and only happens on non-Linux systems.)

---

Another use is to quickly clear the environment using the `-i` option. In legacy *sysvinit* initscripts, which are just shell scripts often launched directly by the sysadmin, it is necessary to make sure the admin's environment does not propagate to the started daemon. (For example, a rogue `$TZ` or `$HOME` might make things really confusing – especially with certain *cron* daemons.)

In this case, the initscript prepares a short environment and starts the daemon using something like:

```
env -i "PATH=/bin:/usr/bin" "LANG=$system_locale" /usr/sbin/crond
```

Answer (score 1):

It's really any program. It is most useful for all those that use any value defined as environment variable. You can pass an environment variable value to any program without actually setting it in your shell (and thereby influencing other programs down the line).

`env ls` runs `ls` without modifying the environment. `env -i ls` resets the environment. On my system, this removes colors from its output, since it unsets `LSCOLORS` and `CLICOLOR`. `env LSCOLORS=GxfxcxhxdxegdggbgdAhAg ls` will run `ls`, passing the specified `LSCOLORS` string and possibly changing how the `ls` output is colored.